# Installing OpenCV with GUI on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

It seems that I have messed things up. I forgot to install some dependencies of OpenCV on Ubuntu. To be specific, I want to install OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04 with GUI support. I noticed that there is a package named `gtk+-2.0` which is required by OpenCV. So I did

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

or some thing like that. It installed alright. I also installed other dependencies specified [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html).

However, when I run `cmake` according to the tutorial, it says that

```
gtk+-2.0` not found
```

so OpenCV will be built without GUI support. Is there any environmental variable that I should set before I run `cmake`?

I can detect `gtk+-2.0` by

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0`
```

which outputs `2.24.23`. Also, I remember adding some search path for `gtk+-2.0`, some thing like

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

Is there anything to do with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm 
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev 
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev 
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy 
sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev 
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

1. sudo wget
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.zip
2. unzip opencv-2.4.9.zip
3. cd opencv-2.4.9
4. mkdir build
5. cd build sudo cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D  INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D
   BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_VTK=ON
6. sudo make
7. sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to clean up the build environment before continuing. `make clean` will not be sufficient. Remove all makefiles and start all over again.
I have just successfully installed OpenCV and ran a video file on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Let me know if I can be of further assistance.